# Progress dialog box in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a simple Windows form app that does things. I'd like a box to show the progress of each step as it's doing these things. Sort of like a console output, except not on the console, but in a display box that is non-interactive to the user. What thing in the VB.NET toolbox do I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a simple [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k63c05yf.aspx) and make it [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx)?

Comment: Either that, or a multi-line label. But I normally prefer the `TextBox` since that allows the user to select and copy the text.

Comment: This, along with a ProgressBar indicator if there are many operations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx

Comment: @Tim Just set the Text-Property

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the text property of the TextBox just use something like `Me.TextBox1.text = "Text here"`. And `TextBox1` refers to the `name` property which you can set in the properties window of Visual Studio.

If you would like to do it under a `progressBar` its a little more involved with how you want to progress it. After you drop it on the form though you can set the `name` property of the `progressBar` then in your code behind do `Me.ProgressBar1.Value = x`. Where `ProgressBar1` is the `Name` property again and `x` is a integer representing the value to set the `progressBar` to.